# Adding a linear model from another dataset in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have a dataset that contains time series information regarding soil elevation from several sampling stations. I have modeled the change in soil elevation over time for each station using ggplot. Now I would like to add a line to my graph that depicts a linear model fit to other geological data over time from a different dataset but I have been unable to do so. I know that I can add the slope and the intercept to my functions manually but I would rather not. 
 My data is as follows..

```
str(SETdata)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1620 obs. of  6 variables:
$ Observation      : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ Plot_Name        : Factor w/ 3 levels "1900-01-01","1900-01-02",..: 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ PipeDirectionCode: chr  "001°" "001°" "001°" "001°" ...
$ Pin              : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 ...
$ EventDate        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ PinHeight_mm     : num  221 207 192 220 212 212 206 209 203 222 ...

str(FeldsparData)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   540 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Benchmark  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
$ Plot       : Factor w/ 12 levels "1a","1b","1c",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 5 
...
$ TotalChange: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Day        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

The graph I have is

```
SETdata %>%
  ggplot()+
  aes(x = EventDate, y = PinHeight_mm, color = Plot_Name, group = Plot_Name)+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point")+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line")
```

And I would like it to include this line

```
reg <- lm(TotalChange ~ Day, data = FeldsparData)
```

My attempts seem to have been thwarted because R does not like that I am using two different datasets.

Comment: `geom_abline()` uses slope and intercept, so you can use it to manually annotate a model fit. [Documentation here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_abline.html)

Comment: Does adding something like `geom_smooth(data = FeldsparData, aes(x = Day, y = TotalChange), method = "lm")` to your ggplot code work?

Comment: When I add the geom_smooth function to ggplot, I get the following error Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Plot_Name' not found

Comment: Try adding inherit.aes = FALSE to the geom_smooth call